# How to pass mediumblob data as a parameter to a procedure in MariaDB

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb, parameter-passing

I am trying to build a procedure which must have a mediumblob as an input parameter. Does somebody has an example of that? I did not find any on the Internet.

Thank you very much.

Jayme Jeffman

Comment: How about reading https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-procedure/ ?!

Comment: Thank you very much for adding a comment. As a matter of fact I am not a beginner. There is not any reference to blobs at the page you ask me to read.

Comment: [ IN | OUT | INOUT ] param_name type: IN param_name MEDIUMBLOB

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB accept parameters of type MEDIUMBLOB. I am using it in CBuilder 10.3 with UniDac components. The trick is using the AsBlobRef property of TUniStoredProc parameter to perform a LoadFromStream method.
Unfortunately UniDac components do not have big examples althoug Devart give a very good support on their forums or by email.